# Accessory Button On a map pin

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MKPinannotation detail disclosure button - present new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195774/mkpinannotation-detail-disclosure-button-present-new-view)

Would any one lemme know how do i get an accessory button (Detail Disclosure) on a map pin and have some event on its click event.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add accessory button to your pin using:

```
yourPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

When you click on accessory button this delegate will be invoked:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
            calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
   //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: @MidhunMP and paras...hey i got the disclosure button but i want that on its click event it should navigate to a web page i.e if the pin is on pune when i clik it it should navigate to wikipedia displaying pune 's information... plzz help out

Comment: @iMNavedShaikh: The `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` will work when you tap on the accessory button. You can load your webpage and other sruffs there. Set your mapview's delegate to self. Then implement the above delegate method.

Comment: so would i need to add a new file for the web page @MidhunMP

Comment: @iMNavedShaikh: If you need to do that, you need to add a new page and create a web view on it and present it modally. Another option is to open that in safari using url loading scheme

Comment: i did it by adding a new file and i import its class and creted its object in the mapview class. Now the thing is where do i write the code for switch i.e pass the url to the prop i created in new web file. coz my mapview file doesnt hav a did select row at index method..

Comment: @iMNavedShaikh: I'm already mentioned you that, when you click on the accessory button the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method is invoked. Check my answer too. You can present a modal view controller from that method.

Comment: kkk...letme chk it... @MidhunMP

Comment: @iMNavedShaikh: ok, please check it, if you stuck anywhere please tell me.

Comment: kkk if i dont get it i will mail you.. @MidhunMP

Comment: hey don wid it...but would you letme know that suppose if i have 2 pins 1on mumbai nd other on pune wid the del mthd i can navigate it to web but hw do we do it for other pin coz it shud show mumbais web..and switch isnt wrking..

Comment: @iMNavedShaikh: you need to add a tag for each pin view. When you click it, check the tag in that delegate method like if(view.tag == 1)

Comment: i tried using tag but wer we need to assign the tag..

Comment: For this you need to implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

Comment: yeah i did dat..wait il mail u the code of it..is it obk @MidhunMP

Answer (score 0):

If you want some different then do

```
        UIButton *DetailViewBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        DetailViewBtn.tag = currentAnnotation.tag;

        [DetailViewBtn setTitle:currentAnnotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [DetailViewBtn addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(annotationBtnPress:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        yourAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = DetailViewBtn;
```

and your method here

```
-(IBAction)annotationBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"raj");
}
```

Comment: Hy thanxx bddy...il try it out n let u knw ... @rajneesh.

Comment: @iMNavedShaikh.. what happen not any upvote why?